# How to convert 1D array into single column 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have an 1D array.

```
my_array([1330.4286, 1330.1406,
          1333.7192, 1333.5702,
          1328.096])
```

can you please tell me how to convert this 1D array into single column 2D array like this_

```
my_array([[1330.4286 ],
          [1330.1406 ],
          [1333.7192 ],
          [1333.5702 ],
          [1328.096  ],])
```

If I type this code `y_test.reshape(y_test.shape[0],-1)` It's doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension:

```
d2 = [[a] for a in d1_list]
```

in numpy:

```
d2 = d1_list.reshape((d1_list.shape[0],1))
```

reshape in 2d accept a tuple defining the shape where `(rows,cols)`